# Snowflake bulk loading select columns auto population

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Please guide me on how to autopopulate select columns (like select *) rather than select $1:col1, $1:col2

`copy into mytable from (select $1:col1, $1:col2 from @staging/x.parquet)`

Comment: Hi - COPY INTO without listing columns is the first syntax option shown in the documentation. Can you be more specific about what issue you are facing?